# Problem in configuration of Micromax MMX 355G in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: configuration, modem, 3g

Hi! I got an error at the last step. 
I am using Micromax MMX 355g 3G modem HSPA 7.2mbps.
Configuration will be very difficult and detection of driver also difficult.
I just did the above steps are fine upto `modprobe` statement and at last statement: `usb_modeswitch -c /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/1dbc:0669`.
I got the error is no driver found, but usb storage driver is found and product id is also found:

```
Looking for target devices ...
   found matching product ID
   adding device
 Found devices in target mode or class (1)
Looking for default devices ...
   found matching product ID
   adding device
 Found device in default mode, class or configuration (1)
Accessing device 006 on bus 001 ...
Getting the current device configuration ...
 OK, got current device configuration (1)
Using first interface: 0x00
Using endpoints 0x01 (out) and 0x87 (in)
Inquiring device details; driver will be detached ...
Looking for active driver ...
 OK, driver found ("usb-storage")
 OK, driver "usb-storage" detached
 Could not send INQUIRY message (error -2)

USB description data (for identification)
-------------------------
Manufacturer: HSPA
     Product: HSPA
  Serial No.: 8444311594054030
-------------------------
Looking for active driver ...
 No driver found. Either detached before or never attached
Setting up communication with interface 0
Using endpoint 0x01 for message sending ...
Trying to send message 1 to endpoint 0x01 ...
 Sending the message returned error -2. Trying to continue
Resetting response endpoint 0x87
Resetting message endpoint 0x01
 Could not reset endpoint (probably harmless): -2
-> Run lsusb to note any changes. Bye.
```

Comment: Similar question with the same answer - maybe merge these? http://askubuntu.com/a/301993

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and write this code:-

```
sudo gedit /etc/modules
```

Press <kbd>enter</kbd>

It will ask for your password, put it and press <kbd>enter</kbd>

then write these lines

`usbserial` press <kbd>enter</kbd>

`option` press <kbd>enter</kbd>

Save the file and close `gedit`.

Now restart your system.

After it open terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and write

`sudo modprobe usbserial`<kbd>enter</kbd>,

give your password, press <kbd>enter</kbd> then type

`sudo modprobe option`press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

- Close the terminal.
- Now connect your modem with the usb port.
- Wait for few second, and you are done.