# Did not detect Micromax MMX353G netsetter

Tags: usb, modem

I had Micromax MMX353G net setter, but it did not detecting on Ubuntu 12.04 onwards versions even in Ubuntu 13.04. And also I try to connect with Sakis3G  (http://www.sakis3g.org/) script run through Terminal. Please help which version Ubuntu OS is best all over ?

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and write this code:-

```
sudo gedit /etc/modules
```

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
It will ask for your password, put it and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> then write these

```
usbserial
```

press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
option
```

press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Now restart your system. After it open terminal and write

```
sudo modprobe usbserial
```

press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, give your password, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> then type

```
sudo modprobe option
```

press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. close the terminal. now connect your modem with the usb port. Wait for few second, and now you are done.