# Problem installing Micromax MMX 355G

Tags: networking, internet, modem

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10.

After much this and that, I was able to install the software on my Windows XP. It then ran automatically. But when I open my Ubuntu, I cannot find a way to install it. The software just contains compressed files which include just more compressed files.

How does one install a modem like this?

Comment: Try this: [Problem in configuration of Micromax MMX 355G in Ubuntu 12.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/296613/problem-in-configuration-of-micromax-mmx-355g-in-ubuntu-12-04).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting up the connection manually
From

Network Manager->Add new connection->Mobile Broadband

Select your Provider name & APN and save it

After that connect it from the network applet

If u want to make "connect automatically" then check the option in the setting of your connection setting

Comment: The option "Mobile Broadband" doesn't come, and that's sort of the entire problem.

Comment: Are you using gnome on ubuntu? or You are in stock?

Comment: I'm running the plain, nice Ubuntu. The option comes when I insert another modem. There must be some commands and stuff to do in the Terminal to run this one.